# Define a recurrence with two variables

Tags: algorithm

I was asked to define and solve a recurrence T(n), as well as represent it in Big-O notation, but am confused with the two variables. I think I am dealing with `f(m,n) = 1 + f(m+1,n-3)` for `n>1`, and `f(1) = m+10` would be my base step? But beyond that I am not sure.

```
int f(int m, int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return m+10;
    else
        return 1+f(m+1,n-3);
}
```

Comment: You say: `f(n,m) ` and then do `int f(int m, int n)` are you sure that your expression is correct?

Comment: Ok, now by `f(1)` you mean `n = 1` since in the condition you're returning it based on the value of `n` I suppose. Would you mind describing the possible value of `m` in that instance?

Comment: note that the run time of this thing does not depend on m.  specifically, you have T(m,n) = 1 + T(m+1,n-3), T(a,1)=T(a,0)=T(a,-1)=1.  a can be anything.  R(n) = 1 + R(n-3) (with R(n)=T(m,n)) and R(1)=R(0)=R(-1)=1.  The run time of T(m,n) is ceil((n+1)/3).

Comment: here's a quiz for you: figure out a way to do this in O(1)

Comment: Step 1 is to put a `printf("m=%2d n=%2d\n", m, n)` at the beginning of the function and then call the function with various small numbers until you understand what the function does. Then everything becomes easy, including thang's O(1) challenge.

Comment: How can you have `f(1)` if `f` is a function of 2 arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved in **O(1)** time. The solution only depends on the value of **n**.

```
f(m,n) = 1+f(m+1,n-3) for n > 1
```

and

```
f(m,1) = m+10
```

Now this can be written as follows,

**f(m,n)=⌊n/3⌋+m+⌊n/3⌋+10**
which equals,

**f(m,n)=2⌊n/3⌋+m+10**

The C code for the function is also given below,

```
int f(int m, int n)
{
    return (2*(n/3)+m+10);
}
```